# How to determine all permutations of a set, with repeated symbols, but *without* "functionally identical" sets

Tags: python, combinatorics

Assume the following set of symbols: [A, B, C]

Assume the following result set size of 4.

I would like to produce a list of all permutations, with repeated symbols, but without "functionally identical" items.

Ie: [A, A, A, A] is "functionally identical" to [B, B, B, B] and thus [B, B, B, B] should **not** be in the final result, etc.

I tried generating the full 3^4 possibilities, then "rotating the symbols", checking one by one if there is a dupe and removing them but I realized this doesn't catch cases where "two symbols swap", and of course, when increasing the number of symbols and set size, there are plenty of other "symbol swap" cases I'm not accounting for. Plus, it seems like "generate the worst case and then prune" is a terrible algorithm, I'm sure there is a much better way.

Here is a manually generated result of the expected output:

```
['A', 'A', 'A', 'A']
['A', 'A', 'A', 'B']
['A', 'A', 'B', 'A']
['A', 'A', 'B', 'B']
['A', 'A', 'B', 'C']
['A', 'B', 'A', 'A']
['A', 'B', 'A', 'B']
['A', 'B', 'A', 'C']
['A', 'B', 'B', 'A']
['A', 'B', 'B', 'B']
['A', 'B', 'B', 'C']
['A', 'B', 'C', 'A']
['A', 'B', 'C', 'B']
['A', 'B', 'C', 'C']
```

(And of course, at some point I want to extend the symbol set size and the result set size to see what results I get.)

(Preferred language is python but I'm not picky, I'm just trying to understand the algorithm)

Edit: Let me clarify my definition of "functionally identical". Essentially all that matters is the "topology" of the result. For example, let's say that random colors are assigned to the symbols once we have the sets generated.

[A A A A] simply means "All the items are the same color", thus, [B B B B] would be functionally identical. There is no difference between the two because we don't know what random color is going to be assigned to A or B, all we know is that they are all the same color.

Another example:
[A A A B] is functionally identical to [B B B C], because again, we don't know what colors will be assigned to what symbols, all we know is "The last color is different from the first three."

The order matters though!
[A A A B] != [B A A A]. In the first example, all items are the same color except the LAST item. In the second example, all items are the same color except the FIRST item.

This is absolutely a mathematical construct, more advanced than simple permutation, I just don't know the name for it.

Comment: I don't understand how `AAAA` is "functionally identical" to `BBBB`.

Comment: Do you mean, there is a permutation of the letters A, B, C which maps one to the other?

Comment: Does "functionally identical" mean having the same number of repeated symbols, so [A,A,A,B] is functional identical to [C,C,C,A]? If not, a precise definition is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a recursive algorithm that does it. The key idea is that to break symmetry between the different letters, we are only allowed to add a letter that has already been used, or the *first* unused letter.

Given a partial solution `t`:

- If `t` has the required length, yield it.
- Otherwise:

  - For each distinct letter already in `t`, recurse by extending `t` with that latter.
  - If `t` doesn't use each possible letter, recurse by extending `t` with the first unused letter.

Here's a Python implementation, as a recursive generator function:

```py
def gen_seqs(letters, n):
    def helper(used, t):
        if len(t) == n:
            yield t
        else:
            for i in range(used):
                yield from helper(used, t + letters[i])
            if used < len(letters):
                yield from helper(used + 1, t + letters[used])
    return helper(0, '')
```

Example:

```py
>>> for t in gen_seqs('ABC', 4):
...     print(t)
... 
AAAA
AAAB
AABA
AABB
AABC
ABAA
ABAB
ABAC
ABBA
ABBB
ABBC
ABCA
ABCB
ABCC
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been banging my head against the wall trying to figure this out. This works perfectly.